# Opening password protected Excel file with Process.Start - don't wait for password

Tags: c#, .net, excel

In my app I need to open a password protected excel file, but I don't want to enter this password (This will user do).
I'm opening it with Process.Start(path) method.
The problem is that my app is opening this file and waits until user will enter the password. So until user won't enter the password my app is waiting.
I want my app to go on with next code line and don't wait for user to enter password.
Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

EDIT:
my code:

```
if (File.Exists(_path))
{               
     //Start the program from _path
     Process program = Process.Start(_path);

}
else
{
     throw new Exception("File does not exist at path: " + _path);
}
```

EDIT:
SOLUTION:
The solution was to start Excel application with argument that is path to the selected Excel file.

```
private void StartProgram(string _path)
{
    //Check if file exist
    if (File.Exists(_path))
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        //Check if file is an Excel sheet
        if (FileIsExcelSheet(_path) && ExcelIsInstalled())
        {
            processInfo.FileName = "Excel";
            processInfo.Arguments = _path;

            Process program = Process.Start(processInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            //Start the program from _path
            Process program = Process.Start(_path);
        }
   }
   else
   {
        throw new Exception("File does not exist at path: " + _path);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the method you are using to start the Excel process.

Comment: Process.Start does not block (by default), please show your code.

Comment: I added the code in EDIT. When I debug it the program stops excatly in the line 'Process program = Process.Start(_path);' and until I enter the password in the Excel file it waits there.

Comment: When I tried the same thing with a password protected Excel file, `Process.Start` immediately returned while Excel was still waiting for a password.

Comment: hm, that's strange, maybe the reason could be that I'm using very old Excel 2002? But why Process.Start method is waiting?

Comment: I tested my app also with Excel 2010 and there is the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the filename as Excel and the Argument as the xlsx path:

```
    Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo{
        FileName=@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe",
        Arguments=_path
    });
```

I guess you could alternatively launch it from another thread, but if your application makes a habit of opening these files then you probably don't want to waste all the threads that way.

Comment: I tried this, but still the same problem. Do you have any more idea how to solve this?

Comment: I had Office 365 on that machine and it seemed to work for me, but this one has 2010 and I see your issue. I was able to modify my solution above to get it to work on Office 2010, but the downside is that you need to know the Excel.exe location. Change Filename to (for example) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe (or wherever your version is installed, then add Arguments=_path to the ProcessStartInfo initialiser. Doesn't need ShellExecute either.

Comment: Yes, exactly this solved my problem. I've added my new code to the question. Thank you very much Adam.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using OLE Automation to open the file (i.e. driving Excel via it's COM automation model, rather than just asking the Windows Shell to start it), then you could work around this by supplying a password in the `Open` call. If you don't have the correct password, then the call will fail, but at least it wouldn't block.

Of course, that's a *much* harder way to open the file... very much a case of "you had one problem, you solved it and now you have 99".